# Lyrics translation in html

Tags: html, translation

How to represent lyrics and corresponding translation strophe in HTML?

**just an example:**

```
Может, поздно, может, слишком рано,        Maybe, it's too late or, maybe, early, 
И о чем не думал много лет,                It has not occurred to me for years,
Походить я стал на Дон-Жуана,              I resemble now Don Juan, really,
Как заправский ветреный поэт.              Like a proper flippant man of verse.
```

How to represent it in SEO friendly and semantic way?

P.S.   I really hate solution with tables and don't want to put original line and translated in one container (I think it's ugly and bad for googgles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Semantically speaking I could see an argument for these being lists or paragraphs.

Me I think I'd go with something like this (apologies for code bloat):

```
<style>
.song
{
  background: #444;
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1.0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.song .lyrics
{
  float: left;
  color: #ddd;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 20em;
}

.song #russian.lyrics { background: #009; }

.song #english.lyrics { background: #090; }   

.song .lyrics p { margin: .5em .2em; }
</style>

<div class="song">
    <div id="russian" class="lyrics">
        <p>Может, поздно, может, слишком рано,</p> 
        <p>И о чем не думал много лет,</p>
        <p>Походить я стал на Дон-Жуана,</p>
        <p>Как заправский ветреный поэт.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="english" class="lyrics">
        <p>Maybe, it's too late or, maybe, early,</p>
        <p>It has not occurred to me for years,</p>
        <p>I resemble now Don Juan, really,</p>
        <p>Like a proper flippant man of verse.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would be inclined to make both "russian" and "lyrics" classes in case there might be multiple songs on a page.

Comment: Most of the lyrics sites I've seen are one song per page so I went with that approach - marginal call though it was. The OP is free to change that of course, should he even use this.

Comment: I don't think marking each line as a paragraph is right semantically. A <br> tag between each line would be better.

Comment: No? My thinking here is that with lyrics each line is a distinct and self-important item, as in poetry, and not in prose.

Comment: Well, I think the same holds for poetry too. In fact line breaks in poetry are pretty much the canonical example of correct use of the <br> tag. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: I don't think that link demonstrates canonicity here. I could eb persuaded either way I think - would make a good SO question if it wouldn't be such a flame-war/poll!

Answer (score 4):

I would just leave off the English translations entirely.  I think most music sounds more impressive if you can't actually understand what the singer is saying, and your example lyrics seem to verify this.  :)

All seriousness aside, I would actually just alternate the original lyrics and the translation with different fonts, like so:

*Je ne parle pas d'un bâtiment*

[I do not speak a building]

*请不要拍我*

[Please do not shoot me]

Comment: +1 for not translating lyrics - literal translations of good lyrics often produce bad lyrics, and if the lyrics are bad in the original language...!

Comment: My favorite Elton John song is "Hold Me Closer, Tony Danza".

Answer (score 2):

You use divs. You put each set of lyrics in a div tag and then use some CSS to format the two divs next to each other such as:

```
.lyrics {
 float: left;
}
```

There are a number of other CSS techniques that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, use divs with CSS in order to achieve the specific effect you want, sans tables. Here's a page with [a pretty comprehensive overview of CSS positioning](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) to get you started. 

As an example of what you might use, try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.lyrics {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
.original {
  float: left;
}
.translation {
  float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="lyrics original">(lyrics here)</div>
<div class="lyrics translation">(translation here)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually think a table makes the most sense here.